# Error sending email with JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

The following code works only when Google's "Allow less secure apps" is ON, if that feature is off I get **javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException**, how do I get it to work when that feature is OFF?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username = "USER-NAME@gmail.com";
    String password = "PASSWORD";
    String to = "USER-NAME@msn.com";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.list(System.out);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject("This is the subject line!");
        msg.setText("This is the actual message");

        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        Transport.send(msg, username, password);
        System.out.println("Message sent!");
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use OAuth.

Comment: this might help: [link](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2)